# How to reverse the transaction if the button is clicked again so that the read and writes of transactions are not increased?

Tags: swift, firebase, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the below code to run a transaction in firestore database upon the button being tapped or clicked. If the condition is already true and the same button is tapped again, how can I reverse the transaction so that the number of reads and writes of transaction are decreased and not increased further? It is just like if we like an instagram post and if tap on the heart button again we remove the like on the instagram post.

```
 db.runTransaction({ (transaction, errorPointer) -> Any? in
    let sfDocument: DocumentSnapshot
    do {
        try sfDocument = transaction.getDocument(likesRef)

    } catch let fetchError as NSError {
        errorPointer?.pointee = fetchError
        return nil
    }

    guard let l1 = sfDocument.data()?["like"] as? Bool else {
        let error = NSError(
            domain: "AppErrorDomain",
            code: -1,
            userInfo: [
                NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Unable to retrieve population from snapshot \(sfDocument)"
            ]
        )
        errorPointer?.pointee = error
        return nil
    }

    // Note: this could be done without a transaction
    //       by updating the population using FieldValue.increment()
    //  let l11 = false
    guard l1 == false else {
        let error = NSError(
            domain: "AppErrorDomain",
            code: -2,
            userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Population \(l1) too big"]
        )
        errorPointer?.pointee = error
        return nil
    }

    transaction.updateData(["like": true], forDocument: likesRef)
    self.createMessageRoom()
    return l1
})
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is here.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am running function on the post to like a comment, for that a transaction will be used, but if the like button is clicked again the previous action of like should be reversed, I mean the comment is not liked, and then if the like is reversed, another transaction will run again and I want this should not happen as it will increase the read and writes, so to not increase the read n write operation what shall be done while reversing the earlier transaction ,this flow may assist to you to understand better          "not Liked >>(one tap) liked>>(second tap) not liked"

Comment: I think you just need some application logic to manage what happens if the user toggles that button.  There is no "reverse transaction" operation in Firestore.  You have to write that logic.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for the advice I will work on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no concept of a "reverse transaction" in Cloud Firestore (nor in other databases that I've worked with). If you have two different actions that are each other's inverse, you will either have to implement two transactions, or find a way to turn the "reversing" into a parameter in a single block of code.

The latter actually seems pretty common for your scenario here, where you use a single transaction with these steps:

1. Read the current value of the document containing likes
2. If the document contains a like for the current user remove it.
3. If the document doesn't contains a like for the current user add it.

If we for example model "has liked"`as`true`and "has then unliked" as`false`, you could do something like:

```
let newLikeValue true
guard l1 == true else {
  newLikeValue = false
}

transaction.updateData(["like": newLikeValue], forDocument: likesRef)
```